# Your message is not signed with DKIM

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, smtp, dkim

I am writing my application in nodejs. At this stage, I'm trying to send emails to the mail-tester.com test environment to see if my emails go to spam, and I'm getting this error: 'Your message is not signed with DKIM'.

I am using AApanel, first I uploaded my project and clicked the SSL button, AApanel using Let's Encrypt generated the necessary certificates and keys for me, but did not generate the public key

[my key and cert here] https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yqIo.png

I copied my private key in order to create a public key based on it, I went into OpenSSL and entered the command:

```
openssl rsa -in dkim_private.pem -pubout -outform der 2>/dev/null | openssl base64 -A
```

Next, I got my public key from the private.

[here is how i set up my public key]https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNgdh.png

Here is my dkim on domain:

```
v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=MIIB...
```

where after the P-tag, there is a public key obtained using OpenSSL.

So the next is my script to send a message:

```
     const tls = require('tls');
     const fs = require('fs');
     const net = require('net');
     const ConvertForSMTP = require('./tools/conv.js');

     const options = {
         key: fs.readFileSync('./keys/my-key.pem'),
         cert: fs.readFileSync('./keys/my-cert.pem'),
         isServer: false
     };

     let netSocket = net.createConnection(25, 'reception.mail-tester.com');

     netSocket.on('ready', () => {
         netSocket.write('EHLO hailmail\r\n');
         netSocket.write('STARTTLS\r\n');
     });

     netSocket.on('data', (chunk) => {
         const res = chunk.toString();
         console.log(res);
         if (res.includes('220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')) {

             let secure = upgrade(netSocket);

             secure.on('secureConnect', () => {
                 let caretka = `\r\n`;
                 console.log(secure.authorized);
                 console.log('IN SECURE');

        secure.write('EHLO hailmail\r\n');

        secure.on('data', chunk => {
            const response = chunk.toString();
            console.log(`Res in secure: ${response}`);

            if (response.includes('221 2.0.0')) {
                secure.destroy()
            }
            else if (response.includes('354')) {

                selectorBody(response, function (value) {
                    console.log(`sending data: ${value}`);
                    secure.write(value + caretka);
                });

                secure.write(`.\r\n`);
            }
            else {
                let request = selectorHeader(response);
                secure.write(request + caretka);
            }

        })
        secure.on('keylog', (line) => {
            console.log(`Line in secure: ${line}`);
        })
        secure.on('close', () => {
            console.log('closed');
        })
    });
}

});

 function selectorBody(res, cb) {
     let command = ConvertForSMTP('buw123.c@hailmail.co.uk', 'test-am6gm86w1@srv1.mail-     tester.com', 'TEST', 'THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE FROM HAILMAIL.CO.UK');
     if (res.includes('End data with')) {
         console.log('in 354');
         for (let key in command.data) {
             cb(command.data[key]);
         }
    }
 }

 function selectorHeader(res) {
     let command = ConvertForSMTP('buw123.c@hailmail.co.uk', 'test-am6gm86w1@srv1.mail-          tester.com', 'TEST', 'THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE FROM HAILMAIL.CO.UK');
    if (res.includes('250-mail-tester.com')) {
         console.log(`sending ${command.mailFrom}`);
         return command.mailFrom;
     }
     else if (res.includes('250 2.1.0')) {
         console.log(`sending ${command.mailTo}`);
         return command.mailTo;
     }
     else if (res.includes('250 2.1.5')) {
         console.log(`sending ${command.commandData}`);
         return command.commandData;
     }
     else if (res.includes('250 2.0.0')) {
         return command.commandQuit
     }
    else {
         return command.commandQuit
     }
 }

function upgrade(skt) {
skt.removeAllListeners('data');
skt.removeAllListeners('error');
skt.pause();
return tls.connect({ socket: skt, secureContext: tls.createSecureContext({ key: options.key, cert: options.cert }), rejectUnauthorized: false }, () => {
    console.log('tlsSocket in the game');
});
}
```

So I use the let's encrypt certificate and private key when I do socket.upgrade (which happens after starttls), but still mail-tester doesn't see my use of the DKIM signature. Maybe someone faced with this, tell me. If I missed something, ask, I will add the code

**EDIT:** So for the first never make the same mistake as i made. Certbot (Let's ecnrypt) doesn't create the certificate for DKIM signing, you can check this out here: [certbot doc](https://certbot.eff.org/faq#can-i-use-certificates-from-certbot-for-code-signing-or-email-encryption)

You should use another service, like DKIM generator, you will get there PRIVATE RSA KEY, PUBLIC KEY, and even ready-to-post DKIM-record for your domain. I wanted to create myself DKIM signing functionality, but i found better variant for nodejs, it calls [mailauth](https://github.com/postalsys/mailauth)

And as said Patrick Mevzek, in rfc [6376](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#appendix-A.3) you can find the example of a letter, and there is a DKIM-Signature line, which you can get, using mailauth.

Comment: Does the email message sent includes DKIM headers? As this level your question may not be really on topic here as it may not be a code problem really, if DKIM headers are missing.

Comment: I missed it probably, but idk what does DKIM headers mean. Could you explain?

Comment: Emails have headers. For DKIM to work there must be an header called "DKIM-Signature".  See example at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#appendix-A.3 ; you need to dump the email generated in raw form and double check this is in it with appropriate values. Otherwise DKIM can not work. In short the email headers include a signature over email content done by using the private key and the recipient fetches the public key from the DNS to double check the signature is indeed legit (and hence the content signed) as generated by a specific private key.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, i have checked rrfc 6376 and then started to look for how to generate DKIN-Sign line correctly, so i found the solution for myself.